# Move attachment from one SPO list to another using Power Automate

Tags: list, attachments, spo, copy

I created a simple Flow to create a new item in list 2 (2 columns should be copied) when an item was created in list 1. But how can an attachment being copied from list 1 to list 2 with the same flow? I am using SharePoint Online.

Thanks for your help!
Simon

---

Hello Matiur and thank you very much for your help!

It works not yet. I can see the attachment in list 2, but if i want to open the attachment (in this case a picture), it opens only a black screen:

[image]

And in the last step (add attachment - to the item list2), I could only choose "AbsoluteUri" for the File Content:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps in your flow.

[image]

### Details 1 & 2

[image]

Comment: You are awesome - thank you very much, it works!! :-)